# returned a value having type `Figure` which is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, lstm, plotly-dash, forecast

I am building a Python Dash application that can be used to predict sales. For Example,

1. A user should select the store ID on the application
2. An LSTM model will be used to forecast the sales
3. A forecast graph should be displayed on the web application

I am getting an error stating "returned a value having type `Figure` which is not JSON serializable." while trying to run the application.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Find the code and output below.

```
####APP Layout#####
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, keras, itertools
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout


app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server

Dataset = pd.read_csv("weeklysales.csv")

df=Dataset[["store_Id", "Normalized_sales"]]

model=load_model("model.h5")


#app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': 'white'},children=[
html.P(html.H1(children='Sales Forecast',style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'height': '60px',
    'line-height': '60px',
    'border-bottom': 'thin lightgrey solid',
            'color': 'black'
        })),
html.Label('store_ID',style={
            'color': 'black',
            'font-size':25
        }),
dcc.Dropdown(id = 'g3',options=[
                                {'label': '11362691', 'value': '11362691'},
                                {'label': '108110', 'value': '108110'},
                                {'label': '145325821', 'value': '145325821'},
                                {'label': '3', 'value': '3'},
                                {'label': '4', 'value': '4'},
                                {'label': '5 or above', 'value': '5'}
                            ],style = dict(
                            width = '30%',
                            display = 'inline-block',
                            verticalAlign = "middle"
                            )),
dcc.Graph(id='example'),

html.Div([html.Button(id='submit_button',
                    n_clicks=0,
                    children='Submit',
                    style={'fontSize': 18, 'marginLeft': '30px', 'backgroundColor': 'white'}
                    )

    ], style={'display': 'inline-block'})
])



@app.callback(Output(component_id='submit-val', component_property='fig'), 
              [Input(component_id='g3', component_property='value')])'''

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('example', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('g3', 'value')]
)

def update_graph(value):
    #print(value)
    value = int(value)
    sales_data=df[df['repoID']==value]
    s_data=sales_data.Normalized_sales
    s_forecast=s_data[-20:].values
    series = np.array(s_forecast)
    series=np.reshape(series,(1,series.shape[0],1))

    predictions = np.zeros(12)
    predictions[0] = model.predict(series, batch_size = 1)
    n_ahead = 12
    if n_ahead > 1:
        for i in range(1,n_ahead):
            x_new = np.append(series[0][1:],predictions[i-1])
            series = x_new.reshape(1,x_new.shape[0],1)
            predictions[i] = model.predict(series,batch_size = 1)
            
    Final_Score=predictions.reshape(12)
    Final_Score[Final_Score<0] = 0

        # data to be plotted 
    x = np.arange(start=1, stop=13, step=1)
    #first = go.line(x, Final_Score)
    #data = [first]
        #print(i)
        #print(rows[i])
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('black') 
    plt.title("Sales for the next 12 weeks")  
    plt.xlabel("Date")  
    plt.ylabel("Sales")
    plt.plot(x, Final_Score, color ="green")  
    return fig


if __name__=='__main__':
    model=load_model("model.h5")
    Dataset = pd.read_csv("weeklysales.csv")
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

When running this app, I am getting the below error.

```
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `<Output `example.figure`>`
returned a value having type `Figure`
which is not JSON serializable.


The value in question is either the only value returned,
or is in the top level of the returned list,

and has string representation
`Figure(432x288)`

In general, Dash properties can only be
dash components, strings, dictionaries, numbers, None,
or lists of those.
```

Please help me with how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem and it was due to the fact that one of the y-values in my Plotly.plot was a data type that dash didn't know (sympy.float). If you work with external modules to calculate results make sure that the returned numbers are floats by inspecting them first before passing them to dash.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a matplotlib figure object, which is not supported in Dash. If you return a plotly figure object instead, it should work.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message with a figure returned from `plotly.express.bar`.