# Unable to update Figure via Dash callback (IncorrectTypeException)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following code that displays a histogram, and I want to use a RangeSlider to update the figure to only show the year range that the user specifies. I followed the standard template of using a callback to update the figure with the values in the slider but I am getting the following error on the callback function:

`IncorrectTypeException: component_id must be a string or dict, found Figure`

I saw someone else with this same error but they were passing a matplotlib figure. I am using a Plotly figure that otherwise displays normally. I saw someone else mention that the types in the source dataframe might matter, but I changed mine from 'object' to 'string' and it did not fix it. Anyone have any insight? Or does anyone know what component_id is supposed to represent? Thanks!!

Here is the similar question I referenced:
[returned a value having type `Figure` which is not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207525/returned-a-value-having-type-figure-which-is-not-json-serializable)

```
fig = px.histogram(df, y = 'Procedure', color = 'LOE')
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(figure=fig),
   dcc.RangeSlider(min = 2000, max = 2020, value = [2000,2020], step = 1,
                   marks={i: str(i) for i in range(2000,2020,1)}, id = 'range-slider')
])

@app.callback(
Output(fig, 'data'),
Input('range-slider', 'value'),
)
def update_table(slider_value):
   if not slider_value:
       return dash.no_update
   new_df = #modify df here
   return px.histogram(new_df, y = 'Procedure', color = 'LOE')

if __name__ == '__main__'
   app.run_server(mode = 'inline')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pointing to this line:

`Output(fig, 'data'),`

It looks like you're trying the new way of passing a component in here, but the error makes it sound like you don't have the right version of Dash for that. You may need to pass in the `dcc.Graph` component instead of the histogram, though.

You can always use a string ID here, which would look like this:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(id='my-output', figure=fig),
   dcc.RangeSlider(min = 2000, max = 2020, value = [2000,2020], step = 1,
                   marks={i: str(i) for i in range(2000,2020,1)}, id = 'range-slider')
])

@app.callback(
Output('my-output', 'figure'),
Input('range-slider', 'value'),
)
def update_table(slider_value):
   if not slider_value:
       return dash.no_update
   new_df = #modify df here
   return px.histogram(new_df, y = 'Procedure', color = 'LOE')
```

Comment: Using a string ID fixed it!
```dcc.Graph(id='my-output', figure=fig)``` and ```Output('my-output', 'figure')``` were the lines I needed. Much appreciated! I wonder why this happens.